# Angular 9 trim directive

Tags: directive, angular9

I have a directive that should trim a value in a input box. The directive trim the value in the form but when I submit it, the value is not trimed.

```
// this code works and the value is trimmed after submitting the form
<input type="text" matInput formControlName="adress" oninput="this.value = this.value.trim()">

// this code trim the value on the form but NOT after submitting the form
<input type="text" matInput formControlName="adress" trimvalue>
```

I am missing something in the directive ?

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[trimvalue]'
})
export class TrimDirective {
    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    @HostListener('input') onInput(event) {
        let value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;

        if (value) {
            value = value.trim();
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = value.trim();

            this.renderer.setValue(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[angular source code - setValue()](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/197f3f4a2677f60cc85ac6656d9300927a611500/packages/core/test/render3/render_util.ts#L538)

you can see `setValue` is woking by `node.textContent = value;`

```js
  setValue(node: RText, value: string): void {
    node.textContent = value;
  }
```

and `textContent` is `string|null`

```js
export interface RText extends RNode {
  textContent: string|null;
}
```

So, I guess `setValue()` didn't work as predicted is cause by typescript's type  go something wrong in background...

You can trim it by `nodeValue`.

```js
this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach((x: ChildNode, i: number) => {
      if (x.nodeName === '#text') {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue.trim();
      }
    });
  }
```